# Time Machine Backup to a Windows computer

Tags: time-machine, windows, time-capsule

Is it possible to do a [time machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Machine_%28Mac_OS%29) backup from a MacBook Pro to a Windows 7 PC?
(i.e. use Windows 7 as a [time capsule](http://www.apple.com/timecapsule/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a [lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/5685547/) on doing exactly this by creating a sparse HFS+ bundle on the Windows machines.  You could use a Linux machine or Amazon S3 using s3fs + encfs too.

Time Machine requires an HFS+ filesystems backup disks like this sparse bundle because Time Machine uses Apple's [unusual](http://www.xkcd.com/981/) directory hard links.

Linux could [theoretically](https://superuser.com/questions/306497/can-linux-mount-a-normal-time-machine-sparse-bundle-disk-image-directory) read the HTF+ sparse bundle but Windows sounds doubtful.

Comment: I really liked the xkcd comic :-) nice touch!

Comment: Yes, it seemed appropriate.  :)